# Cannot interate through HTMLCollectionOf<Elements> - How can I iterate through this HTMLCollectionOf<Elements>

Tags: javascript, iteration

I can see the HTMLCollectionOf with the follwing code

```
        let cards = document.getElementsByClassName(this.card_class) ;
        console.log( "CCC cards are ")
        console.log(cards)
```

[Here is what I get from Chrome conole](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXR6F.jpg)

But I cannot iterate through this HTMLCollection

I have tried using different iterations method (see below) and none will iterate through the collection.

```
        let cards = document.getElementsByClassName(this.card_class) ;
        console.log( "CCC cards are ")
        console.log(cards)

 console.log( "cards length with object,keys ",  Object.keys(cards).length)
 console.log( "cards length with cards.length ",  cards.length)

        Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(this.card_class)).forEach(
            function(element, index, array) {
                console.log( "cccccc with Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName for")
                console.log(element.tagName);
            }
        );


        Array.prototype.forEach.call(cards, function(el) {
            // Do stuff here
            console.log( "cccccc in Array.prototype.forEach.call ")
            console.log(el.tagName);
        });
        const length = Object.keys(cards).length;
        for ( var i=0; i<length;i++){
            console.log( "cccccc in Array.prototype.forEach.call ")
            console.log(cards[i].tagName);
        }

        const s =  Array.from(cards);
        console.log(" Array.from(cards) is ")
        console.log(s)

        Array.from(cards).forEach( (e ) =>{
            console.log( "cccc  Array.from(cards).forEach( (e ) ")
            console.log(e)
        });
```

[As you can see from the chrome console image, none of the iterations go through](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWvOL.jpg)

Can you please let me know what I am doing incorrectly? Thanks!

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce. Please include a [mre].

Comment: You're trying to iterate through your cards too early. At the time you run `getElementsByClassName` and the `forEach()`, your cards don't exist, you need to do run your loop after the cards have been populated.